# RHEL 7.1 compatibility with Java 1.8.45

Tags: java, rhel7

I am interested in knowing that if there are any know issues while running applications using JVM 1.8.45 on RHEL 7.1.

Comment: If this is important then ensure that you are using a supported platform at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have long to use RHEL, but I deployed on Fedora 21 and Fedora 22 the Java 1.8, full support, without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no as such problem using jvm 1.8.45 on RHEL 7.1 as I am using it. Working perfectly fine.

Check this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) for JVM compatibility with different OS.